# Asus DSL Modem Routers: How do you enable bridge mode / avoid double NAT

Tags: nat, adsl-router, dsl-modem, asuswrt

For Asus DSL modem routers (for example DSL-N16), how can I enable bridge mode so that a separate router handles all the routing etc. and the DSL-N16 just acts like it is in modem-only mode?

I want to avoid double NAT and just set it to bridge mode or something similar.

DSL-N16 acts as a modem only, passes through all traffic over Ethernet to the router connected to it. The router actually has the public facing IP from the ISP and handles NAT and routing for all clients connected to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annoyingly, this mode **is** available on all Asus modem routers (`DSL-` models) but is hidden.

The FAQ page that tells you how to do this is titled: [How to let LAN client get the public IP?](https://www.asus.com/uk/support/FAQ/1015722/)

But this allows you to do the following:

1. Use the public IP your ISP provides
2. Turn your modem router into a modem only bridge mode
3. Avoid double NAT completely

There are many different configurations on the FAQ page, **so I recommend you go on there to set it up based on your modem router and ISP DSL type**, but the one that worked for me (VDSL with a DSL-N16 as the modem and an RT-AX92U as the router) was:

1. Set up your modem's WAN like so with your own settings for things like VLAN ID that your ISP provides. Namely pick a new service unit (optional, you can also update the service unit `Service 1` if that's all you need) and set the WAN connection type to bridge on LAN Port 1: [image: WAN set up on modem]
2. Enable the `Remove VLAN TAG from WAN` setting on your modem's LAN: [image: LAN set up on modem]
3. Then on your router make the WAN port of your router connect to the LAN 1 port of your modem. And set up PPPOE on your router's WAN settings (use the username/password and other settings from your ISP): [image: router WAN settings]

Again, don't forget to go to the FAQ page to set it up for your specific use case. For example, if your ISP uses ADSL instead of VDSL the steps above will not work.